# Different behavior of apply(str) and astype(str) for datetime64[ns] pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with datetime information in pandas and wanted to convert a bunch of `datetime64[ns]` columns to `str`. I noticed a different behavior from the two approaches that I expected to yield the same result.

Here's a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

```py
import pandas as pd

# Create a dataframe with dates according to ISO8601
df = pd.DataFrame({"dt_column": ["2023-01-01", "2023-01-02", "2023-01-02"]})

# Convert the strings to datetimes
# (I expect the time portion to be 00:00:00)
df["dt_column"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt_column"])

df["str_from_astype"] = df["dt_column"].astype(str)
df["str_from_apply"] = df["dt_column"].apply(str)

print(df)
print()
print("Datatypes of the dataframe")
print(df.dtypes)
```

**Output**

```
   dt_column str_from_astype       str_from_apply
0 2023-01-01      2023-01-01  2023-01-01 00:00:00
1 2023-01-02      2023-01-02  2023-01-02 00:00:00
2 2023-01-02      2023-01-02  2023-01-02 00:00:00

Datatypes of the dataframe
dt_column          datetime64[ns]
str_from_astype            object
str_from_apply             object
dtype: object
```

If I use `.astype(str)` the time information is lost and when I use `.apply(str)` the time information is retained (or inferred).

Why is that?

(Pandas v1.5.2, Python 3.9.15)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The time information is never lost, if you use `2023-01-02 12:00`, you'll see that all times will be present with `astype`, but also visible in the original datetime column:

```
            dt_column      str_from_astype       str_from_apply
0 2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-01 00:00:00  2023-01-01 00:00:00
1 2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00  2023-01-02 00:00:00
2 2023-01-02 12:00:00  2023-01-02 12:00:00  2023-01-02 12:00:00
```

With `apply`, the python `str` builtin is applied on each `Timestamp` object, which always shows a full format:

```
str(pd.Timestamp('2023-01-01'))
# '2023-01-01 00:00:00'
```

With `astype`, the formatting is handled by `pandas.io.formats.format.SeriesFormatter`, which is a bit smarter and decides on the output format depending on the context (here other values in the Series and the presence of a non-null time).

The canonical way to be explicit is anyway to use [`dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
# without time
df["dt_column"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# with time
df["dt_column"].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: That's interesting, thanks! I was hoping I could use `astype` because I want to convert a few columns with mixed types to string, and it seemed faster than `apply`. Unfortunately, it appears to be smarter than I want it to be :D